# PHP JavaBridge, ejemplos y/o usos

Tags: php, java, tomcat, apache2

me gustaría que pudieran brindarme por favor un ejemplo de como llamar una clase de Java desde PHP con JavaBridge.

Revisando todos los posts que tienen relación a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548612/javabridge-php-java-how-to-call-a-java-class-from-a-php-file tienen enlaces donde ya no se encuentra información o no es correcta, ninguna de las respuesta fue marcada como correcta y la única que me parecía prometedora no me llevó a ningún lugar

Saludos

Comment: en stackoverflow en ingles viene esta pregunta te comparto el enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548612/javabridge-php-java-how-to-call-a-java-class-from-a-php-file espero sea de ayuda, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoseLuisEsparza revisaré la pregunta y respuestas, muchas gracias, de lo contrario seguiré molestando por acá, jeje
Saludos

Comment: @JoseLuisEsparza te comento que he revisado todos los posts que tienen relación al que me indicas, sin embargo tienen enlaces donde ya no se encuentra información o no es correcta, ninguna de las respuesta fue marcada como correcta y la única que me parecía prometedora no me llevó a ningún lugar, lo que ando buscando es donde me expliquen desde cero como utilizar esa interoperabilidad entre lenguajes, gracias